# Auto-mock some constructor arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I've written this code:

```
BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties = Mockito.mock(BackOfficeProperties.class);
Mockito
    .when(backOfficeProperties.getUrlFrontOffice())
    .thenReturn("http://some.valid.url");

this.auditService = Mockito.spy(
    new AuditService(
        backOfficeProperties,
        Mockito.mock(AuditFactory.class),
        Mockito.mock(AuditDao.class),
        Mockito.mock(RedisDao.class),
        Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class),
        Mockito.mock(I18nResourceBundleMessageSource.class)
    )
);
```

Is there any more elegant way to write this code?

Comment: how do you initialize `backOfficeProperties`? It seems odd that you pass a "real" object into your *to-test-class*

Comment: I've edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mockito annotations to do this for you:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class AuditServiceTest {
    @Mock 
    private BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties;
    @Mock 
    private AuditFactory auditFactory;
    @Mock 
    private AuditDao auditDao;
    @Mock 
    private RedisDao redisDao;
    @Mock 
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Mock 
    private I18nResourceBundleMessageSource i18nResourceBundleMessageSource;
    @InjectMocks
    private AuditService auditService;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
       Mockito
           .when(backOfficeProperties.getUrlFrontOffice())
           .thenReturn("http://some.valid.url");
    }

    // your tests
}
```

Some explanation:

- `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` executes your tests with the given `Runner` implementation, in this case a mockito runner, which initializes all the annotated fields
- `@Mock` indicates that you want to mock said object, it's like `Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class)`
- `@InjectMocks` indicates that you want all the `@Mock`s you've declared to be injected into the annotated field, so it just calls the constructor with the given arguments.

I also think that you don't need to `spy` on your service that you want to test. If you still need it though you can use the `@Spy` annotation **after** the `@InjectMocks` annotation

Comment: Could you help on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458063/mockito-mocked-object-not-injected-on-constructor-argument?noredirect=1#comment95724658_54458063) out?