# Mockito: mocked object not injected on constructor argument

Tags: java, mockito

I've this constructor:

```
public class AuditsLoaderService {
    public AuditsLoaderService(
        BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties,
        FrontOfficeInterfaceService frontOfficeService,
        AuditService auditService,
        I18nResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource,
        MonitorService monitor
    ) {
      // some code
    }
}
```

and `AuditService` is:

```
public class AuditService {
    public AuditService(
        BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties,
        AuditFactory auditFactory,
        AuditDao auditDAO,
        RedisDao auditRedisDao,
        ObjectMapper objectMapper,
        I18nResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
    ) {
```

Into my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MalformedAuditsTest {

    @Mock
    private BackOfficeProperties backOfficeProperties;
    @Mock
    private AuditFactory auditFactory;
    @Mock
    private AuditDao auditDao;
    @Mock
    private RedisDao redisDao;
    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Mock
    private I18nResourceBundleMessageSource i18nResourceBundleMessageSource;
    @Mock
    private MonitorService monitorService;
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private AuditService auditService;
    @InjectMocks
    private FrontOfficeInterfaceService frontOfficeService;
    @InjectMocks
    private AuditsLoaderService auditsLoaderService;

}
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting an `NulPointerException` inside my `AuditsLoaderService` since **`auditService` is `null`**.

It seems it's not injected.

I've annotated it as:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private AuditService auditService;
```

Should I add some more code/annotation?

**EDIT**

I've just realized neither `frontOfficeService` neither `auditSerice` are injected on.

So, **it seems all `@InjectMocks` fields are not injected on others ones**

Comment: And whats in `AuditService`?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using `@Spy`? Spying on object is most of the times a bad idea.

Comment: **it seems all `@InjectMocks` fields are not injected on others ones**

Comment: Is there any reason on using `Mock` and `InjectMocks` annotations on the same field?

Comment: Mmm... I think you mean `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks`. Yes, I need to spy it. I've to say that **frontOfficeService** is not injected as well.

Comment: I think it is just one InjectMocks should be in a test class which would be a class under test. Rest of the classes should be Mock or Spy.

Comment: use inject mock but do initialize them with @Before annotation

Comment: **Don't** use `@InjectMocks` on multiple fields, not that Mockito couldn't handle it, but you're trying to test 3 different classes at the same time (which is *never* a good idea). Split those up, and create 3 different test classes where every one just declares the `@Mock`s it uses. This will probably resolve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
@Mock
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

because your `AuditService` constructor requires it

**EDIT**: It's probably easier to create objects manually by passing mocks in corresponding constructor

Comment: Sorry, it was a mis-writting. It's also coded into my code.